# CodeIgniter- CSS & JS are not loading on server

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, hosting

I'm working on a codeigniter project, it's working fine on localhost but CSS,JS and Images folders are not loading when I uploaded it on server. I have these folders in a folder named "assets".
Also

```
I'm getting 404 error.
```

Only my default controller link is working, I'm not able to redirect to other controllers.
My file structure is as shown in the image.

[image: Screenshot of file structure]

Comment: check your .htaccess file, config file corresponding to live server

Comment: my .htaccess file has following code: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule> I have changed $config['base_url'] and $config['index_page'] = ' '; in config file.

Comment: Please follow the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. first add "echo 'hi'; die;"  in index.php in root level.
2. if get output "hi" then check rounting, and controller name.
3. if get 404 error than check your .htaccess(root level), .htaccess(in application floder),config.php, db.php files. correspondin to live server
4. And set define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development'); for fetch errors

Answer (score 0):

Prefix all of your assets with your `base_url` like this:

```
<link href="<?= base_url('path_to_asset_relative_to_your_fcpath') ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

And make sure to set your `base_url` correctly in your `config.php`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your .htaccess

See below an example i have used for Godaddy shared hosting

```
RewriteOptions inherit
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on RewriteBase /your_root/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```